# c++ how to make a function which takes an input of a derived class, within the original abstract class

Tags: c++, class, input, methods, abstract

Lets say I've got an abstract class called Turtle. In the class I've got a function on its own thread, which takes an input of the Turtle. 
The compiler says that I cannot use an input of abstract type Turtle. 
What I want to happen is for the function to take an input of a derived class, and not the abstract Turtle class. How should I fix this?

```
#include <thread>

class Turtle 
{
    std::thread T_thread;
    public:
    virtual void foo(Turtle T) = 0;

    //tried making this virtual as well
    void do_stuff(Turtle T) 
    {
        foo(T);
    }

    Turtle() 
    {
        T_thread = std::thread(do_stuff, this);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Turtle` is an abstract data type then you can't declare a variable of this type. But you can declare a variable whose data type is a pointer or reference to this type.

Use a reference to `Turtle` in the signature of the method:

```
void do_stuff(Turtle &T)
```

The dynamic type of the actual parameter which is passed to `do_stuff` can never be of type `Turtle`, because it is abstract, but it can be of a type which is derived from `Turtle` (if the derived class is not abstract too).